# SQL to update a table with rows in the same table but with different criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table like so:

```
business_positions
id   code   description_1   description_2
```

For some reason it is wrongly populated for the first half with the `description_1` column filled in and the `description_2` column empty, and the second half is the opposite:

```
id  |code|description_1|description_2
 900|   1|Senior Manager|(empty)
 901|   1|President|(empty)
 902|   1|Board Member|(empty)
 903|   2|Another Description|(empty)
...
2000|   1|(empty)|Desc
2001|   1|(empty)|Desc2
2002|   1|(empty)|Desc3
2003|   2|(empty)|Desc4
...
```

I want to update the table to have both the descriptions filled in the same row, matching rows through the `code` field and respecting the insertion order (ie no sorting). The `ids` are always unique. The result I am after is:

```
id  |code|description_1|description_2
 900|   1|Senior Manager|Desc
 901|   1|President|Desc2
 902|   1|Board Member|Desc3
 903|   2|Another Description|Desc4
```

and then delete the second half, with ids from 2000 on.

How do I do that?

Tried this with no luck:

```
UPDATE 
    business_positions A
LEFT JOIN business_positions B ON (A.code=B.code )
SET
    A.description_2 = B.description_2
WHERE
    A.description_2=''
AND
    B.description_2<>'' 
AND 
    A.id<>B.id
```

Comment: in description_2 column u only need to insert Desc1,Desc 2....... right?

Comment: Problem solved, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use following query to update

```
update business_positions t1 inner join business_positions t2
on t2.id=t1.id+1100
 set t1.description_2=t2.description_2
```

Then delete unwanted rows using following query

```
delete from business_positions where id>1999;
```

Comment: No, please read again the question. If I delete the rows before the update, I'll have no data to update the rows with.

Comment: @vulkanino - from your first answer, i thought you just need to insert Desc1,Desc2 ....

Comment: I need to merge descriptions after all.

Comment: Your answer is correct if I know the IDs and if they are consecutive, but it's not a general solution.

Comment: @vulkanino - in your case there is no relation(i meant unique relation) between two related rows which we need to combine except row id, so there is no general solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;with CTE  
AS  
(  
    select description_2 from business_positions where description_1 = " "  
)  

update A  
Set description_2 = B.description_2  
FROM business_positions A  
INNER JOIN CTE B  
ON A.description_2 = " "  

DELETE business_positions  
where description_1 = " "  


select * From business_positions
```

Comment: what kind of error? You need to replace single quote (' ') in place of double quote( " ")

Comment: I don't get the syntax ";with CTE", and the query doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using Sql Server or my sql?  CTE is common table expression. it works like table.

Comment: MySQL as per tags.